# LiveLink to Sharepoint Migration

Tags: migration

I have livelink to Sharepoint 2010 migration project to undertake but I have no idea where to start from and what to do. I am hoping someone out here has an idea of what course to take or a pointer to an article that describes this would be great.

Comment: livelink? Is it Migration between servers, across domains, or from MOSS to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: You can pass the project to me and we can share the price ;)

Comment: it is migrating LiveLink data (list, libraries, emails) to a sharepoint 2010

the other is migrating from Moss 07 to BPOS

Thanks

i am not getting paid to this ...its all learning value but i'l be grateful if you could give me an idea of how i could do this

Answer (score 0):

[MOSS 2007 to SharePoint 2010 Migration](http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2011/09/migrate-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint.html) and make sure you have [Updates/Upgrades installed on MOSS necessary for Migration](http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2010/06/migrating-to-sharepoint-2010.html)

And here is [Microsoft Technet Explaining Complete Upgrade plans](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx)

and since I don't have much information about BPOS, here is what I found:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onlineservicessharepoint/thread/f4cc9d4c-d82c-4ebd-b8e2-ce92f7602937

I hope this helps!